# sending a transaction requires a signer (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.7.0)

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, alchemy

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
// import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import contract from './RPSLS.sol/RPSLS.json'

const { ethers, JsonRpcProvider } = require('ethers');
// Signer = provider.getSigner()

function App() {
  const { ethereum } = window;
  const [address, setAddress] = useState('Connect Wallet');
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState('');
  const [play, setPlay] = useState('');
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();

  const contractAddress = "0x3d791aebF11D469DC1604eb8c028E7885845fEBf";

  const alchemyProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/7aCctjFhE6l0ERCD17i1kSz4tHSk_Kla"
  )

  const walletProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    ethereum
  )

  const getContractData = new ethers.Contract(
    contractAddress,
    contract.abi,
    alchemyProvider,
    signer
  )

  const sendContractTx = new ethers.Contract(
    contractAddress,
    contract.abi,
    walletProvider
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    ethereum.on("accountsChanged", (accounts) => {
      setAddress(accounts[0])
      const getbal = async () => {
        const balance = await ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_getBalance",
          params: [accounts[0], 'latest']
        })
        setBalance(ethers.formatEther(balance));
      }
      getbal();
    })
    ethereum.on("chainChanged", (chain) => {
      console.log(chain);
    })
  })

  const player = async () => {
    const data = await getContractData.play();
    setPlay(data);
    console.log(data);
  }

  const changeChain = async () => {
    await ethereum.request({
      method: "wallet_addEthereumChain",
      params: [
        {
          chainId: `0xaa36a7`,
          chainName: "Sepolia Testnet",
          nativeCurrency: {
            name: "SEPOLIA",
            symbol: "ETH",
            decimals: 18,
          },
          rpcUrls: ["https://rpc.sepolia.org"],
          blockExplorerUrls: ["https://rpc.sepolia.org"]
        }
      ]
    })
  }

  const sendTx = async () => {
    await ethereum.request({
      method: "eth_sendTransaction",
      params: [
        {
          to: '0xEf657b09Bb40DD929eF04DfbC4905Ca697ecAbaE',
          from: address,
          value: `0x${(parseInt(ethers.parseEther('0.02'))).toString(16)}`,
          chainId: '0x3',
        }
      ]
    })
  }

  const requestAccount = async () => {
    // await ethereum.request({
    //   method: "wallet_requestPermissions",
    //   params: [{
    //     eth_accounts: {}
    //   }]
    // });

    const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
    setAddress(accounts[0]);

    const balance = await ethereum.request({
      method: "eth_getBalance",
      params: [accounts[0], 'latest']
    })

    setBalance(ethers.formatEther(balance));
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <a
          className="App-link"
          onClick={requestAccount}
        >
          {address}
        </a>
        <a className='App-link'
        >
          {balance}
        </a>
        <a className='App-link'
          onClick={changeChain}
        >
          add Chain
        </a>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          onClick={sendTx}
        >
          Send Transaction
        </a>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          onClick={player}
        >
          play
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```